# How can I create URLs using jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I created my website mainly using jQuery and AJAX.

The whole content is being loaded by clicking on a specific ID, so I do not use the classic "href" currently.

However, **I would like to create URLs** with jQuery that work when they are called directly by the web browser and also by clicking of course.

Could you give me some hints how this could be realised based on the following code?

Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#inhaltsbereich").load("assets/pages/index.php");
AOS.init();

    $("#startseite").click(function(){

        document.title = "Startseite";

        $("#inhaltsbereich").load('assets/pages/index.php');
    AOS.init();
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);

    });

    $("#sprachen").click(function(){

        document.title = "Die Sprachen des Webs";
        $("#inhaltsbereich").load('assets/pages/sprachen.php');
        AOS.init();
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);

    });

    $("#portfolio").click(function(){

        document.title = "Portfolio";
        $("#inhaltsbereich").load('assets/pages/portfolio.php');
        AOS.init();
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);    

    });

    $("#kontakt").click(function(){

        $("#inhaltsbereich").load('assets/pages/kontakt.php');
        AOS.init();
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
        document.title = "Kontakt";
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);

    });

});
```

Comment: Look up `window.location.href` & `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @ASPiRE Thank you! But that's not what I was looking for. I found the following function which modifies the URL: 

`window.history.pushState({}, "", "/sprachen");`

But you can not call this URL directly by your webbrowser - and that is what I want to achieve without reloading the page.

Comment: try returning false

Comment: @CorAngar I started a codepen in search for a solution, didn't find it but did upgrade your code significantly, making it shorter and more flexible: [**codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxpgNE**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxpgNE?editors=0011). Thought you might appreciate it.

Comment: @Will Hoskings Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a bit of jQuery like so:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $(".pjax").load(this.getAttribute("href"));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json" class="href">hello there, click me!</a>
<div class="pjax">pjax me here</div>
```

This example gets a JSON file from Github, and displays it in a div. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! So that technically works. But if I call the URL directly(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json) it won't be processed with jQuery and AJAX of course.

But I would like to create SEO friendly URLs which can be called directly by the user or a search bot. Like:

- www.mypage.com/home
- www.mypage.com/contact
- www.mypage.com/portfolio

Is that possible using jQuery and AJAX?